# Linear Algebra - Determine the value of the real number $k$ for which $u⃗ ∈ Span(v⃗_ 1,v⃗_ 2,v⃗ _3)$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

How would I go about  doing this? I just don't know what to do if they span in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Hint: Since it is clear that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent, the matrix formed with $u,v_1,v_2,v_3$ as the columns would be invertible if and only if $u\notin \text{Span}(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.  What do you know about the determinant of invertible matrices?

Comment: If I gave you a value for $k$ can you say whether or not $\vec{u}$ is in the span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $u$ is spanned by $v_1,v_2, v_3$ you can find constants $\alpha, \beta, \gamma $ such that $$ u=\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2 +\gamma  v_3$$

For the moment ignore the fourth coordinates and just solve for the constants using the first three coordinates of your vectors.

You will find that $  \alpha =6, =-3,\gamma=7$

Now use these constants to find the fourth coordinate of $u$ using the fourth coordinates of $ v_1,v_2, v_3$

My answer was $k=8$